# strange tableView.reloadData() behavior

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am trying to make simple firebase realtime chat app in swift. I have node in my database where number of unread messages is stored/

[image: My database]

I have custom tableview cell which has label for displaying number of unread messages

```
 class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

var message: Message? {
    didSet {
        setNumberOfUnreadMessages()
}

fileprivate func setNumberOfUnreadMessages() {
    if let partnerId = message?.chatPartnerId(), let selfId = message?.selfId() {

        let unreadMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("unread-messages").child(selfId).child(partnerId).child("numberOfUnreadMessages")
        unreadMessagesRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let count = snapshot.value as? Int {
                self.unreadMessagesCountLabel.isHidden = false
                self.unreadMessagesCountLabel.text = String(count)
            } else {
                self.unreadMessagesCountLabel.isHidden = true
            }
            print(snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

My tableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? UserCell
        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell?.message = message
        return cell!
    }


func observeUserMessages() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    // getting reference to current user's node
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let userId = snapshot.key
        // getting reference to partners node in user's node
        let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid).child(userId)
        userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)
                if let chatPartnerId = message.chatPartnerId() {
                    self.messagesDictionary[chatPartnerId] = message
                }
                self.attemptReloadOfTableView()
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }, withCancel: nil)
    ref.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.key)
        self.messagesDictionary.removeValue(forKey: snapshot.key)
        self.attemptReloadOfTableView()
    }, withCancel: nil)
}


// Big thank to Brian Woong)))))
var timer: Timer?

private func attemptReloadOfTableView() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleReloadTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func handleReloadTableView() {
    self.messages = Array(self.messagesDictionary.values)
    self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in
        return (message1.timeStamp?.intValue)! > (message2.timeStamp?.intValue)!
    })
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

When I start my app every tableView.cell shows correct number of unread messages from database. When I start to send messages, tableView reloads and begins to show the number of unread messages from sender not only on his cell, but on ALL cells. Moreover in console I see that it gets more and more snapshots from database with every upcoming message.

What happens? How to fix this strange bug?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let unreadMessagesRefHandle = unreadMessagesRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let count = snapshot.value as? Int {
                self.unreadMessagesCountLabel.isHidden = false
                self.unreadMessagesCountLabel.text = String(count)
            } else {
                self.unreadMessagesCountLabel.isHidden = true
            }
            print(snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)
        unreadMessagesRef.removeObserver(withHandle: unreadMessagesRefHandle)
```